# russian language in PayPal Android MPL

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can I set russian language for PayPal lib standard Activity? I use

```
pp.setLanguage("ru_RU")
```

but it's not work.

Comment: Could it be ru-RU (not with underscore?)

Comment: Thanks, but it also does not work.

Comment: What PayPal library are you using?

Comment: Might I suggest using the [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/)?